# Flutter error when run : [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging, flutter-debug

My problem is when I run the application **(New flutter project without any more coding)** on my android mobile the following error appears:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on INE LX1 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57844/bB70idmswSU=/ws
Syncing files to device INE LX1...
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
D/AwareBitmapCacher(30301): handleInit switch not opened pid=30301
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
I/ViewRootImpl(30301): jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
E/        (30301): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
```

And when I tried another phone, this problem does not appear
Knowing that it does not affect the performance of the application and continues to print hundreds times I stop the debug.
**It's only from my mobile.**
I tried to restart it, delete the app and re-run it and the same problem still printing.

Comment: I'm facing the same have you got any updates on this.

Comment: @BaraaAljabban Not yet.. if you have any new tell me please

Comment: I believe this is a hawawei devices Issue.
try to change the device. it worked for me.